# Переменная не определена, а почему я не шарю 1с

Tags: 1с, переменные

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ОтборКатегорияПриИзменении(Элемент)
    Список.Отбор.Элементы.Очистить();
    ЭлементОтбора = Список.Отбор.Элементы.Добавить(Тип("ЭлементОтбораКомпоновкиДанных"));
    ЭлементОтбора.ЛевоеЗначение = Новый ПолеКомпоновкиДанных("КатегорияКачества");
    ЭлементОтбора.ВидСравнения = ВидСравненияКомпоновкиДанных.Равно;            
    ЭлементОтбора.ПравоеЗначение = ОтборКатегория;
    ПолучитьИтог();
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПоказатьВсё(Команда)
    Список.Отбор.Элементы.Очистить();
    ОтборКатегория = "";
    ПолучитьИтог();
    
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере  
Процедура ПолучитьИтог()  
        Если Не ОтборКатегория.Пустая() Тогда       
        Запрос = Новый Запрос;
        Запрос.Текст = 
        "ВЫБРАТЬ
        |   СУММА(Фурнитура.Количество) КАК Количество,
        |   КОЛИЧЕСТВО(Фурнитура.Код) КАК ВсегоФурнитуры,
        |   СУММА(Фурнитура.ЗакупочнаяСтоимость) КАК ЗакупочнаяСтоимость
        |ИЗ
        |   Справочник.Фурнитура КАК Фурнитура
        |ГДЕ
        |   Фурнитура.КатегорияКачества = $КатегорияКачества";
        Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("КатегорияКачества", ОтборКатегория);
        
        РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить().Выгрузить();
        ВсегоФурнитуры = РезультатЗапроса[0].ВсегоФурнитуры;
        ИтогоЗакупочнойСтоимости = РезультатЗапроса[0].ЗакупочнаяСтоимость;
        КоличествоФурнитуры = РезультатЗапроса[0].Количество;               
    Иначе
        Запрос = Новый Запрос;
        Запрос.Текст = 
        "ВЫБРАТЬ
        |   СУММА(Фурнитура.Количество) КАК Количество,
        |   КОЛИЧЕСТВО(Фурнитура.Код) КАК ВсегоФурнитуры,
        |   СУММА(Фурнитура.ЗакупочнаяСтоимость) КАК ЗакупочнаяСтоимость
        |ИЗ
        |   Справочник.Фурнитура КАК Фурнитура";        
        РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить().Выгрузить();
        ВсегоФурнитуры = РезультатЗапроса[0].ВсегоФурнитуры;
        ИтогоЗакупочнойСтоимости = РезультатЗапроса[0].ЗакупочнаяСтоимость;
        КоличествоФурнитуры = РезультатЗапроса[0].Количество;       
    КонецЕсли;              
КонецПроцедуры
```

Ошибка:

```
{Справочник.Фурнитура.Форма.ФормаСписка.Форма(77,11)}: Переменная не определена (ОтборКатегория)
        Если Не <<?>>ОтборКатегория.Пустая() Тогда       (Проверка: Сервер)
{Справочник.Фурнитура.Форма.ФормаСписка.Форма(88,50)}: Переменная не определена (ОтборКатегория)
        Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("КатегорияКачества", <<?>>ОтборКатегория); (Проверка: Сервер)
{Справочник.Фурнитура.Форма.ФормаСписка.Форма(63,33)}: Переменная не определена (ОтборКатегория)
    ЭлементОтбора.ПравоеЗначение = <<?>>ОтборКатегория; (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)
```

Comment: А чему равна эта переменная `ОтборКатегория` в процедуре `&НаСервере  
Процедура ПолучитьИтог()`

Comment: Я 1С не знаю, но вроде получается переменная `ОтборКатегория` не определена. А она как-то попадает на сервер с клиента?

Comment: Мало вводной информации. Покажите скрин, что там на форме.